# Add Font no BundleConfig

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

Estou querendo colocar uma **fonte** que está em um *link*, tentei dessas duas formas e nenhuma funciona, simplesmente minha página não carrega a fonte. Segue códigos:

**Primeira forma:**

```
var linkFont = "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all";
                bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/lib/metronic/assets/global/css").Include(
                    "~/lib/metronic/assets/global/css/components.min.css",
                     "~/lib/metronic/assets/global/css/plugins.min.css"));
```

**Segunda Forma:**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/lib/metronic/assets/global/css").Include(
                "~/lib/metronic/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
                "~/lib/metronic/assets/global/css/components.min.css",
                 "~/lib/metronic/assets/global/css/plugins.min.css"));
```

Qual seria o meu erro?

**____EDIT add head**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Metronic Admin Theme #2 | Blank Page Layout</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <link href="/lib/metronic/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/lib/metronic/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/lib/metronic/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/lib/metronic/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/lib/metronic/assets/global/css/components.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/lib/metronic/assets/global/css/plugins.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/lib/metronic/assets/layouts/layout2/css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/lib/metronic/assets/layouts/layout2/css/themes/blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
```

Comment: Abra o console do navegador e veja os erros que ocorreram.

Comment: os únicos erros que aparecem são de imagens que eu não estou utilizando ainda em meu tema.

Comment: Esta no Chrome? Se não, tente verificar o console pelo chrome, se estiver já e não tiver erros de fontes e/ou css aperte Ctrl+U e copie o "source" gerado e posta aqui a parte aonde fica os estilos. Conseguiu entender?

Comment: adicionei o cabeçalho, pois estou usando o chrome e nao apareceu os erros

Comment: Esta estranho, porque o CSS parece OK, as fontes estão em que pasta?

Comment: As fontes tbm está ok, se eu clicar no link gerado no "source" ele abre o arquivo da fonte. Se add igual da primeira forma via HTTP, nem aparece o link em meu head. 

Outra questão, se eu ir manualmente no código e add o link, funciona as fontes perfeitamente.

Comment: Mas a segunda forma causa algum erro no console?

Comment: Tenta adicionar isto antes de tudo `bundles.UseCdn = true;`